# Migrating Sample Projects from Keil to EmIDE

Tags: assembly, gcc, arm, embedded, cortex-m

I am embarking on a project and would like to use EMIDE because it is OpenSource and the project budget is limited.  I have some [LPC1343](https://www.olimex.com/Products/ARM/NXP/LPC-P1343/) sample projects which are for Keil and the blinking led project works but I encounter a problem when I try to enable timer32 by calling:

```
enable_timer32(1);
```

The problem is that the program gets stuck. The only difference between Keil and EMIDE in the source code and header files is the start-up files.  Keil start-up is in assembly and contains more IRQ vectors and the EMIDE is in C and states that it is a minimum set-up for Cortex m3.  Since EMIDE is a GCC compiler I understand it needs a startup file in C.  I cannot figure out how the start-up file needs to be amended or if this would solve the problem…

My question is as follows:

1. How can I modify the EMIDE startup file so that the program does not get stuck when I enable timer32?

Similar topics to this have been posted before but none have been fully resolved, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33297943/arm-arm-none-eabi-gcc-cant-recognize-assembler) I get the same error when I use the Keil start-up in EMIDE.

Comment: This is where you earn your embedded programming wings.  Hook up the debugger and find out where it's stuck. Maybe you don't have a vector installed for the timer interrupt, so it's going to the default vector and spinning?

Comment: Yes @Russ Schultz , I think you are right that it is the interrupt vector that is not installed for the timer interrupt.  I am finding it very difficult to understand how to add it, any pointers would be gratefully received.  the relevant bit of startup.s is below.

Comment: `    .section .isr_vector
    .align 2
    .globl __isr_vector
__isr_vector:
   

    /* External interrupts */
    .long    Default_Handler
    
    .size    __isr_vector, . - __isr_vector`

Comment: I don't know why your example only lists one vector entry, since that will only apply to the first interrupt coming out of the NVIC.  You can either put your entire vector table in the startup.s file by following the example that's already there, or you can poke the values in later by writing to the appropriate address.